# Do Phones running Ubuntu Touch have remote ability to remove apps, wipe phone - aka killswitch?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

Android (when using google services) and iPhones have the ability to remove apps (used for removing malicious and expired apps) and also remotely wipe/disable the phone (in event of theft).

Do phones running Ubuntu Touch have these features ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, but you can already do this with [Prey](https://preyproject.com/) regardless of the device (phone, tablet). It has an [Ubuntu installer](https://preyproject.com/download).

Besides that ... on the [development mailing list](https://lists.launchpad.net/ubuntu-phone/msg07626.html) there is a proposal ...

> So i came to me the idea of some cloud service like (android device manager) to handle this issue. The app must be delivered by default and should be registered with the user account email at first time phone setup. This will be register the user email into the cloud service with the phone or device imei and one imei can only have one user email acount (owner) entry, so the real first owner of the device will have the power of track, and manage the device online.

... that got positive feedback.

Notable comment on this ...

> The system has support for click packages which cannot be removed by
>   the user. However, if the phone is plugged in to USB and the Android
>   development tools are used, then the device can be wiped completely
>   clean, from underneath the OS. There's nothing we can do about that in
>   the OS itself right now, and any anti-theft support at that low level
>   would have to be implemented by the hardware vendors, not necessarily
>   as part of the Ubuntu OS that runs on the device.